# has_object_permission method doesn't work Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, permissions

I want to check in my ModelViewSet if user can create the invitation for the other user to his company. I have 4 models:

```
# Abstract model TimeStampedModel
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        # abstract = True to enable models inherit from TimeStampedModel
        abstract = True

# Custom User model
class User(AbstractUser, TimeStampedModel):
    # Make these fields not to be null
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', default='profile-pic.webp')

    # Assing base user manager for admin panel
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

```
# Create your models here.
class Company(TimeStampedModel):
    VISIBILITY_CHOICES = (
        ('hidden', 'Hidden'),
        ('visible', 'Visible for all'),
    )

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    visibility = models.CharField(max_length=15, 
                                  choices=VISIBILITY_CHOICES, 
                                  default='visible')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Company"
        verbose_name_plural = 'Companies' # Plural naming

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    


# Interactions between users and companies
class CompaniesUsers(TimeStampedModel):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('accepted', 'Accepted'),
        ('revoked', 'Revoked'),
        ('rejected', 'Rejected'),
    )

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(default='pending', choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.company} - {self.user} - {self.status}"
```

I created the custom permission class that checks if user can create the invitation for the user to the company. If user is not owner of the company - access denied to create the invitation.

My `permissions.py`:

```
class IsUsersCompany(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_authenticated
    
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):        
        return obj.company.owner == request.user
```

Here is my ModelViewSet in `views.py`:

```
class CompaniesUsersModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CompaniesUsers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompaniesUsersModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            self.permission_classes = (IsUsersCompany, )
        return super().get_permissions()
```

But this permission class doesn't work. Anybody can create the invitation for the another user to the company even if the user is not owner of the company

## What did I tried

I've tried to get company id directly from the Company model using obj.company. I also tried in has_permission method check if request.method == 'POST'

I expect that when I have a company_1 with owner_id = 1 and user with id 2 tries to create the invitation for the another user to the company_1, it gives him the error that access is denied. When user with id 1 do it - it creates a new invitation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your **IsUsersCompany** permission class. You're currently checking if the **obj.company.owner == request.user**. However, in the context of creating a new invitation, the obj does not exist yet because you are in the process of creating a new object.

To enforce this permission for creating invitations, you should override the **has_permission** method and check the conditions there. You need to make sure that the user creating the invitation is the owner of the company.

Here's how you can modify your **IsUsersCompany** class to achieve this:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsUsersCompany(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == 'create':
            company_id = request.data.get('company')  # Adjust the field name accordingly
            if company_id is not None:
                try:
                    company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
                    return company.owner == request.user
                except Company.DoesNotExist:
                    return False  # Return False if the company doesn't exist
        return True  # For other actions, permission is granted

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.company.owner == request.user
```

In this code:

In the has_permission method, we check if the action is '**create**'. If it is, we extract the company ID from the request data (make sure to adjust the field name). We then try to get the corresponding Company object. If the company exists and its owner is the same as the **request.user**, we return True. If the company doesn't exist or the owner is not the **request.user**, we return False. For other actions, permission is granted.
In the **has_object_permission method**, you can keep the existing logic, which checks if the **obj.company.owner** is equal to the **request.user**. This ensures that a user can only manipulate their own company.

**Make sure to adjust the field name in request.data.get('company') to match the name used in your POST request data.**

Comment: Thank you so much! You've solved my problem.